# An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dynamic, viewmodel

I'm trying to join two tables. User and Scoreboard

ViewModels>ScoreboardVM.cs

```
public class ScoreboardVM
{
public IEnumerable<dynamic> Scoreboards { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
var db = new GameDBDataContext();
var userList = (from s in db.Scoreboards
               join u in db.Users on s.User equals u.UserId
               select new { UserName = u.UserName }).Take(5);

var viewModel = new ScoreboardVM();
viewModel.Scoreboards = userList;

return View(viewModel);
```

View

```
@model Project.ViewModels.ScoreboardVM
    @foreach (var item in Model.Scoreboards) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.UserName) }
```

The last line returns the error "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operator" and I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you aree getting is because the public `IEnumerable<dynamic> Scoreboards`  is dynamic and     `@foreach (var item in Model.Scoreboards)` which is dynamic is not supported by the lambda expression